# Echo is treating html code as text

Tags: php, html

I have a text box and I'm pulling a field from MySQL that uses commas to represent a new line. So each comma would be a new line in the text box. I now want to display each line in a bulleted format, so each line (separated by the comma) has a bullet. My problem is the echo that is used to create the HTML code is being treated as text in the box. So the comma is working to show it as a separate line item, but it is displaying the tags as text.

The code:

```
<textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="ingredients">
<?php 
$list = explode(',', ($RECIPE->ingredients));

echo "<ul>\n";
foreach($list as $ingredient)
{
    echo "<li>$ingredient</li>\n";
}
echo "</ul>";
?>
</textarea>
```

What I get in the text box is:

```
<ul>

<li>ingredient 1</li>

<li>ingredient 2</li>

<li>ingredient 3</li>

<li>adfadfadfad</li>

<li>ingredient 4</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: You can't display HTML inside of a textarea...

Comment: You may do this using contentEditable, search for it.

Comment: @RomanHocke All contentEditable does is allow a static non-form element to be edited in plain text. It has nothing to do with HTML markup being rendered in that element.

Comment: If I can't do it inside of a textarea, how would I display it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be to create a bullet list with something like:

```
echo "<textarea>";
foreach($list as $ingredient)
{
  echo "&bull;$ingredient\n";
}
echo "</textarea>";
```

Wouldn't be a true unordered list however.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/57Hg8/)